# How to view information of partitions in a table?

Tags: mysql, partition

How can I view partition details of a table, like how many partitions are there in a table and storage size of each partition?

Comment: found the answer:
SELECT * FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE table_name ='table_name'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get this kind of information, try this page:
    Visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-info.html

Comment: TL;DR `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Answer (score 65):

I recommend using Table Inspector in MySQL Workbench, it gives you lot of useful information including most data related to table partitions.

The data it displays is from the query:

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.partitions WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table' AND PARTITION_NAME IS NOT NULL`